How does passive in English contrast to German passive conceptually?
I know that in English, intransitive verbs build no passive. However, it seems so in German that they do Refer.
There is only one passive voice structure, but many passive tenses due to ample number of tenses in English, while in German there is two passive voices.
The passive voice in German can be either used to convey the semantics of focusing on the action than actor, and with the choice of zustand- or vorgangpassiv, we can indicate the completion/incompletion of the accent.
How do all of this lead to a difference in the way we think about the passive voice in German vs English? I am particularly interested in the difference caused by intransitive verbs.

The definition of a passive construction is that the first participant of the situation is not expressed in the clause, at least not as subject of the clause. In short, passive blocks the appearance of an agent or perceiver/experiencer as the subject. This is the same in German and English. "Focusing on the action" is a side effect that can play a role in some contexts and can be absent in other contexts; the passive voice does not express any particular content (and in this, it is different from a "tense"). The so called focusing effects of passives are a combination of  passive constructions and a particular information structure of the clause and a function in a context, so they can be derived from other properties of the clause/context. This means that highlighting/backgrounding functions of a passive construction in a language interacts with all its other grammatical properties, so there is no short answer to such questions (though I suppose there ultimately are answers).
In German there are a number of constructions that combine the passive (taken as blocking of the agent) with other contents. It is doubtful whether the "Zustandspassiv" is a real passive, but if it is, it often combines a resultant state reference with the passive effect. A more convincing analysis is that it is an adjectival construction. Then there is a so-called "modal passive" in German: "man tut das" -- "das ist zu tun" (this must be done). This construction has a passive component and a modal component (visible as "must" in the translation), so I think you can separate that from a passive as such.
Languages may differ in the kind of verbs they allow to undergo passive formation. I don't know where the grammatical switch is that turns impersonal passives on and off :) English does not have passives from intransitive verbs, but German and Norwegian, for example, do, and Norwegian otherwise has a clause structure that has many things in common with English (it's basically SVO and has expletive subject pronouns just as English; but it is also verb second like German).
So I think your question is a topic for a whole book...
